# Google Cloud Run 404 Error on internal traffic between services

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I am currently trying to connect two Google Cloud Run services. Both use the default service account, are deployed in `europe-west1`, require no IAM-authentication and only accept internal traffic (and load balancing traffic). I have following architecture

```
Load Balancer
    |
    ` /service -------> service-0 -------> service-1
```

`service-0` acts as reverse proxy that adds some authentication headers and is connected to `service-1` via its `https://<service-1>.run.app` url. Whenever I try to connect to `service-1` from the Internet (via Load Balancer and `service-0`) I get a 404 error from the ingress sitting in front of `service-1`. I can verify that `service-0` forwards the request correctly.

However when I expose `service-1` to the internet, I reach the service without any problems.

This post [Google Load Balancer to Cloud Run giving 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66168829/google-load-balancer-to-cloud-run-giving-404) suggests that it is an issue with europe-west1 region, but I cannot simply switch the region. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How the redirection is done? do you have details?

Comment: Cloud Run is either public or private. If your service is not public, then you need VPC connectors. However, there is no Cloud Run <-> Cloud Run VPC connector. Only VPC connectors from Cloud Run to a VPC. Configure your service to be public and use authorization (IAP) to allow/block traffic.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Its a basic NGINX reverse proxy, which only adds header fields to the request. It maps from `my-service.domain/service` to `<service-1>.run.app/service`, so no path rewriting, etc

Comment: @JohnHanley. Even when `service-1` is public, I can reach it via its address, but not via `service-0`. The weird thing is that the request from `service-0` which goes to `/service` gets blocked by the ingress (the famous 404), while when I connect via the `service-1`'s address, it does not.

Comment: What are the header fields? Do you change the host header? If not, try to put the value of the service 1 URL, it might be your issue.

Comment: I am not changing the hoast header, I add two custom X-Test and X-Auth headers. I will check that and come back to you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time now, it turned out to be a Problem with Google Cloud Run in europe-west1. We contacted support and switched to GKE.